# Best way to Organize & Maintain Localizable Strings?

Tags: ios, xcode, string, localization, localizable.strings

We have a project with multiple Languages enabled, so each language has its own `Localizable.strings` file. During development we are constantly creating more strings (in english) adding them at the end of our `Localizable.strings (base)` ,and until the translation is done, also we add them to the other Localizable files. We have around 3000 Strings so the

**ISSUE:** For one languages we got the strings translated, by only a bunch of them, so there are like 60% of keys and translations missing. So we have to merge, somehow, with the Base file to include the missing `KEYS` and `Strings`, as our `KEYS` are kind of non readable like this:  `APP_SETTINGS_MENU_ITEM_SCREEN_ALWAYS_ON` so we don't display the missing `KEYS` but its English translation.

**QUESTION:** Is there a better way to do this? a way to organize the strings, and make sure that all `Localizable.strings` have all `KEYS` and we can **export** & **import** the missing strings for translation?

Answer (score 1):

I have good experience with Crowdin, it works really well with collaboration and defining multiple projects.

Cheaper alternative is to do the management in spreadsheets: https://github.com/xavierha/localize-with-spreadsheet